# Проверка содержимого ячейки массива

Tags: java

Есть массив Mus, как можно проверить, что в Mus[2] содержится число или символ? Если можно, напишите пример кода. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос некорректно сформулирован. Массив ведь сам по себе типизирован. Или у вас Object[] ?

Answer (score 3):

Если предположить, что mus это char[], то можно просто проверить

Character.isLetter(mus[2]) или Character.isDigit(mus[2])

Answer (score 1):

если вам нужно проверить есть ли какое-то конкретное число/символ в массиве, то можно так:

```
  Arrays.binarySearch ( array, key );
```

если же у вас массив object [], тогда так:

```
  final Object [] a = null; // обьявить правильно
  if (a[0] instanceof Character )
  {

  }
  else if (a[0] instanceof Number )
  {

  }
```

если массив char[] тогда см. ответ [@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m)

Comment: Вы опять невнимательны. Почитайте же что пишут в javadoc про binarySearch. Или поинтересуйтесь, что такое бинарный поиск. Массив должен быть отсортирован перед поиском. И тогда элемент уже не будет вторым.. вряд ли автор имел в виду что-то такое.

Comment: Arrays.binarySearch ( Arrays.sort(array), key );


p.s. и все же я считаю, что если "бубна" нет, можно предлагать разные варианты. пусть автор сам выбирает что ему надо.

Answer (score 0):

Character.isLetterOrDigit(mus[2])